# How to do Url patterns in servlets web.xml

Tags: servlets, url-pattern, path-parameter

I have a question on if this is possible to do. I have a profile servlet that has 2 url patterns, /profile and /profile/*  .So in my project I have a user use GET /profile to get all of the profiles in JSON. Each profile has a favorite team string. Also, I use /profile/* for getting specific profiles by doing /profile/2 for example. Then I have profileFavTeam servlet that I want to get all of the data of the profile favorite team. So I need to get the profiles ID so I want the url to be /profile/"ID"/favteam and this would return the teams statistics.

So for example, If the profile ID is 2 has a favorite team called Liverpool, and I entered /profile/2/favteam, it would show the stats of Liverpool

So would my url for profileFavTeam in web.xml look like this because i want the user to put a number in ID   /profile/*/favteam ?

But would this work if I have /profile/* url pattern in my profile servlet?

Comment: Is this for a new project or for reconfiguring a legacy project?

Answer (score 0):

This would not work. You basically haven path mapping (ending with /*) or extension mapping (beginning with *.). See section 12.2 of the Servlet spec

> In  the Web application deployment  descriptor,  the  following  syntax  is  used to define mappings:
>
> ■ A string beginning with a  ‘/’  character and ending  with  a  ‘/*’  suffix  is  used  for path mapping.
>
> ■ A string beginning with a  ‘*.’  prefix is used  as  an extension mapping.
>
> ■ The  empty string  ("")  is  a special URL pattern that exactly maps  to the application's context root,  i.e.,  requests  of  the form http://host:port//.  In  this case  the path info  is  ’/’  and the  servlet  path and  context  path is empty string  (““).
>
> ■ A string  containing  only  the  ’/’  character indicates  the "default" servlet  of the application. In this case the  servlet path  is the request URI minus the context  path and the  path info is  null.
>
> ■ All other  strings are used for exact  matches  only.
>
> If the  effective  web.xml  (after merging information from fragments and annotations) contains  any url-patterns  that  are mapped  to multiple servlets then the deployment  must fail.

You should implement the Front Controller pattern, with a single Servlet receiving all the requests, and delegate them to the processing objects according to the pattern.